# Set `file.encoding` from `pom.xml`

Tags: java, maven

What incantation do I put into `pom.xml` which will be equivalent to

```
export JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS='-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8'
```

in `.profile`?
I tried

```
<configuration>
    <file.encoding>UTF-8</file.encoding>
</configuration>
```

in `maven-compiler-plugin` and

```
<properties>
    <file.encoding>UTF-8</file.encoding>
</properties>
```

in top level and it did not work.

The main idea is to set this from `pom.xml`, ***NOT*** from the environment 
(I have **no** control over what environment this will be run under).
Again, I am not interested in any solution which modifies `.profile` et al.

Comment: okay, I now know how to do **file.encoding=UTF-8**; alas, I still get **Charset.defaultCharset()** return **US-ASCII** instead of **UTF-8**. ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
    <configuration>
     ...
     <systemProperties>
        <systemProperty>
          <name>propertyName</name>
          <value>propertyValue</value>
        </systemProperty>
        ...
     </systemProperties>
    </configuration>
```

This should work. At least it works for me with other maven plugins.

Comment: THANKS!! is there a way to set these for all plugins without having to repeat the systemProperties or [systemPropertyVariables](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/system-properties.html) block for each plugin?

Answer (score 6):

The [default solution](http://maven.apache.org/general.html#encoding-warning) is to use the following:

```
<project>
  ...
  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>
  ...
</project>
```

and the [maven-compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#encoding) has a different configuration and in particular uses the above property.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to specify the encoding on unit test level you can use the following solution.
This is set on startup of the plugin

```
 <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.19.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <skipTests>${skip.unit.tests}</skipTests>
      <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
      <argLine>${surefireArgLine} -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8</argLine>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```