# Set `defaultCharset` from `pom.xml`

Tags: java, maven, character-encoding

This is a follow up to [set `file.encoding` from `pom.xml`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10386509/850781).
I need to make sure that **Charset.defaultCharset()** returns **UTF-8**.
When I run

```
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS='-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' mvn clean compile test package
```

I get that.  However, I do not have any control about how `mvn` is invoked, so I need to put something into `pom.xml` which would set the default charset to `utf-8`.
Which `systemPropertyVariables` do I set?

EDIT:
I do have

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

and

```
<configuration>
  <systemPropertyVariables>
    <file.encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</file.encoding>
    <charset>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</charset>
  </systemPropertyVariables>
</configuration>
```

they do not help.  `defaultCharset` is still `US-ASCII`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the following property in the pom:

```
<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

maven-compiler-plugin uses this property to set the Java compiler `-encoding` option.

See: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#encoding

Comment: I have that, it does not help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try including that setting in the MAVEN_OPTS environment variable, examples in [Maven Docs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-configuring-maven.html) and [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2819853/java-heap-space).

Or, if you don't want to configure a global environment var, the Codehaus [properties-maven-plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/set-system-properties-mojo.html) might work too, depending on your use case.